# Unable to Edit the Style of MediaElement

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I am trying to create a Custom Media Element , but While trying to do so , I am not able create the media Element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Wont be able to CustoMize the MediaElement as MediaElement is a Sealed Class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement(VS.95).aspx

Instead You can use MediaPlayer ,  that is present in Expression Blend. Open ExpressionBlend and search for MediaPlayer .

Add this to your page , now you can customize the look and feel of the mediaPlayer with ease.

This MediaPlayer is from the team of ExpressionBlend.